# SPI slave ISR not being called randomly

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

So I am trying to have a full-duplex high-speed(I'll be reducing the delay to microseconds once the below problem is solved) comm. between two Arduino Unos. Here is the code below:

Master:

```
volatile uint8_t rdata;

#define SCK   13  // D13 = pin19 = PortB.5
#define MISO  12  // D12 = pin18 = PortB.4
#define MOSI  11  // D11 = pin17 = PortB.3
#define SS    10  // D10 = pin16 = PortB.2

void SPI_MasterInit(void)
{
  /* Set MOSI and SCK output, all others input */
  //DDR_SPI = (1<<DD_MOSI)|(1<<DD_SCK);
  pinMode(MOSI, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
  pinMode(SCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  /* Enable SPI, Master, set clock rate fck/4 */
  SPCR = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (0 << SPI2X) | (0 << SPR1) | (0 << SPR0) ;
  SPCR |= _BV(CPOL);
  //SPCR |= _BV(CPHA);

}

void SPI_MasterTransmit(uint8_t data) {
  PORTB &= ~(1<<2);
  SPDR = data;
  //asm volatile("nop");
  while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
  rdata = SPDR;
  PORTB |= 1 << 2;
  Serial.print("data "); Serial.print(data); Serial.print(" rdata "); Serial.println (rdata);
 
}

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  PORTB |= 1 << 2; //digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  SPI_MasterInit();
}

void loop (void)
{


  for (byte i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    SPI_MasterTransmit(i);

    //Serial.print(m);
    delay(100);

  }
}
```

Slave:

```
volatile boolean process_it;
volatile byte indx = 129, c = 0;


#define SCK   13  // D13 = pin19 = PortB.5
#define MISO 12  // D12 = pin18 = PortB.4
#define MOSI 11  // D11 = pin17 = PortB.3
#define SS    10  // D10 = pin16 = PortB.2


void SPI_SlaveInit(void)
{
  /* Set MISO output, all others input */
  //DDR_SPI = (1<<DD_MISO);
  pinMode(MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(SS, INPUT);
  /* Enable SPI */
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE); // SPI Enable, sets this Arduino to Slave
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE); // SPI interrupt enabled
  SPCR |= _BV(CPOL);
  //SPCR |= _BV(CPHA);
}


void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (115200);

  SPI_SlaveInit();

}


// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{

  SPDR = indx;
  indx--;
  if (indx < 121)
    indx = 129;
  c = SPDR;
  process_it = true;

}




void loop (void)
{
  if (process_it) {

    Serial.println (c);

    process_it = false;


  }

}
```

Below output shows the o/p of the master on the left and slave one the right:

[image]

The master prints the data it has sent(to the slave, "data" variable) followed by the data it has received (from the slave, "rdata" variable). The slave simply prints the received data (from the master).

If you look carefully at the pic you would see that the master sometimes gets the same data (in the next cycle)  it has sent (in the current cycle) (0 and 4 in the pic). At the same time, the slave fails to receive exactly that data (0,4). Also, you can the value of 'indx' is not decremented and the master receives the decremented value in the next cycle. These two things prove that the Slave ISR is not being called randomly (hence the data in the SPDR is not read which is then echoed back to the master plus the index variable is not decremented). Is there a solution to this? I would be really grateful if someone could help me with this.

**Edit**: I face the exact same problem with the default arduino SPI library, here is the code:

Master:

```
#include <SPI.h>
volatile byte m=0;
void setup (void)
{
    pinMode(MOSI, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
    pinMode(SCK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
   
   
 
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
 
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
 
  SPI.begin ();
 
   
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
}


 
   
     
void loop (void)
{
for(byte i=0; i<10; i++){ 
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  m = SPI.transfer (i);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
      Serial.print("data "); Serial.print(i); Serial.print(" rdata "); Serial.println (m);
  delay(100);
}
}
```

Slave:

```
#include<SPI.h>

volatile byte c = 0, indx =129;
volatile boolean process_it = false;
void setup (void)
{
  pinMode(MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(SS, INPUT);

  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
  Serial.begin (115200);

 SPI.attachInterrupt();         


}  // end of setup



// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
      
      SPDR = indx;
      indx--;
      if (indx < 121)
        indx = 129;
      c = SPDR;
      process_it = true;

  

}  // end of interrupt service routine (ISR) SPI_STC_vect

 void loop (void)
    {
      if (process_it) {
    
        Serial.println (c);
    
        process_it = false;
    
    
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the SPI library that does all this for you and has examples that are known to work?

Comment: @Majenko Two reasons, I have observed the exact same problem with the SPI library and I need a C implementation instead of C++;

Comment: Can I suggest, then, for our benefit, that you show us the SPI library based variant (since it's easier for us to follow)? If the two show the same problem it's not your code as such, it's your methodology that is flawed.  Also showing what you *expect* the outputs to show would help.

Comment: @Majenko I have added the SPI equivalent code. The thing is since the SPI interrupt is not getting called sometimes, you can see that the slave is missing data byte from the master (the master is receiving its own data after a cycle since the slave is not clearing/writing the SPDR register). I would like the slave to receive all the data that is being transmitted by the master and vice versa. I wouldn't want the master to receive its own data.

Comment: The part where you write `indx` to `SPDR` before reading `SPDR` and put in `c`, looks odd to me. It probably works because it's internally buffered, but it looks very wrong to me. I can't see anything in the datasheet that suggests this would work. I'd try putting `c=SPDR` before `SPDR=indx`

Comment: @Gerben I have tried that as well. It doesn't change the situation at all. I am still missing ISR calls at random on the slave side.

Comment: I'm stumped. Try using a different Arduino board. Or swapping them.